# Why are the read test results so different even with the same disk

Tags: hard-drive

I have two HD130 in my PC for two years. I ran a victoria surface scan for both of them yesterday, and the result is horrible, but when I connect them to an external hdd docking device, they suddenly returned to normal.
[When connected to motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh9hN.png)
[When connected to external hdd docking device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxgBh.png)

Motherboard: Gigabyte B360 HD3P
CPU: Intel Core i5-8400
Memory: 2 x Kingston 8G DDR4-2400

What is the problem here? I have absolutely no idea, I've changed PSU from Vp550p to NE550 Gold, and also changed the data cable, the problem is still there.

I've tested ST3000DM008, same problem. I'm sure it's not a toshiba problem

Comment: Suggests a poor SATA interface/bus on your motherboard.

Comment: The dips are pretty regular, it could be something on the PC accessing the disk periodically and interfering with the benchmark.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks for your reply. But if it's some software problem why the problem disappeared when the disk was connected to an external docking device?

Comment: @spikey_richie That is possible, but I really don't want to buy a new board to test 

Comment: Because whatever is accessing that disk when it's internal isn't accessing external disks.

Comment: @gronostaj You're right! I entered into safe mode to run surface scan, the dips actually disappeared. I'm so relieved that it's not a hardware problem. But to find which program triggers the problem is difficult. Anyway thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dips are pretty regular, it could be something on the PC accessing the disk periodically and interfering with the benchmark. Whatever is accessing that disk when it's internal apparently isn't accessing external disks.

This dip pattern is quite common for system disks, by the way.

<sub>(reposting my suspicions from comments after confirmation from OP that they're accurate)</sub>

Comment: I finally found out that it's this Moo0 System Monitor I'm using causing the problem. More specifically, the dips appear only when HDD temperature monitors are on. Because it only shows temperatures of internal drives, so that's why the problem only happened on internal ones. Still don't know why it caused the dips.